# Check whether a DLL is registered using Inno Setup

Tags: dll, inno-setup

My setup that I created using Inno setup mainly registers some DLLs.

Now I would like to add some conditional behavior. A certain path shall be taken if another DLL is installed/registered on the system.

**Is it possible to use Inno setup to detect whether a certain DLL is registered in Windows?**

The DLL I want to check is not from me. The only thing I know is its name, but I don't know about any COM objects or CLSIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like "DLL registration" as such. Only COM objects are registered. So you **have to know**, what  COM objects the DLL does register; and then check for those.

Only other thing you can do, is it to traverse whole `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` looking for an entry with the DLL. But that may take tens of seconds even on a fast machine.